# Java ThreadPoolExecutor: Updating core pool size dynamically rejects incoming tasks intermittently

Tags: java, multithreading

I am running into an issue where if I attempt to resize a `ThreadPoolExecutor`'s core pool size to a different number after the pool has been created, then intermittently, some tasks are rejected with a `RejectedExecutionException` even though I never submit more than `queueSize + maxPoolSize` number of tasks.

The problem that I am trying to solve is to extend `ThreadPoolExecutor` that resizes its core threads based on the pending executions sitting in the thread pool's queue. I need this because by default a `ThreadPoolExecutor` will create a new `Thread` only if the queue is full.

Here is a small self-contained Pure Java 8 program that demonstrates the problem.

```
import static java.lang.Math.max;
import static java.lang.Math.min;

import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class ThreadPoolResizeTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // increase the number of iterations if unable to reproduce
        // for me 100 iterations have been enough
        int numberOfExecutions = 100;

        for (int i = 1; i <= numberOfExecutions; i++) {
            executeOnce();
        }
    }

    private static void executeOnce() throws Exception {
        int minThreads = 1;
        int maxThreads = 5;
        int queueCapacity = 10;

        ThreadPoolExecutor pool = new ThreadPoolExecutor(
                minThreads, maxThreads,
                0, TimeUnit.SECONDS,
                new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>(queueCapacity),
                new ThreadPoolExecutor.AbortPolicy()
        );

        ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
        scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(() -> resizeThreadPool(pool, minThreads, maxThreads),
                0, 10, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        CompletableFuture<Void> taskBlocker = new CompletableFuture<>();

        try {
            int totalTasksToSubmit = queueCapacity + maxThreads;

            for (int i = 1; i <= totalTasksToSubmit; i++) {
                // following line sometimes throws a RejectedExecutionException
                pool.submit(() -> {
                    // block the thread and prevent it from completing the task
                    taskBlocker.join();
                });
                // Thread.sleep(10); //enabling even a small sleep makes the problem go away
            }
        } finally {
            taskBlocker.complete(null);
            scheduler.shutdown();
            pool.shutdown();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Resize the thread pool if the number of pending tasks are non-zero.
     */
    private static void resizeThreadPool(ThreadPoolExecutor pool, int minThreads, int maxThreads) {
        int pendingExecutions = pool.getQueue().size();
        int approximateRunningExecutions = pool.getActiveCount();

        /*
         * New core thread count should be the sum of pending and currently executing tasks
         * with an upper bound of maxThreads and a lower bound of minThreads.
         */
        int newThreadCount = min(maxThreads, max(minThreads, pendingExecutions + approximateRunningExecutions));

        pool.setCorePoolSize(newThreadCount);
        pool.prestartAllCoreThreads();
    }
}
```

Why should the pool ever throw a RejectedExecutionException if I never submit more that the queueCapacity+maxThreads. I am never changing the max threads so by ThreadPoolExecutor's definition, it should either accommodate the task in a Thread or to the queue.

Of course, if I never resize the pool, then the thread pool never rejects any submissions. This is also hard to debug since adding any sort of delays in the submissions makes the problem go away.

Any pointers on how to fix the RejectedExecutionException?

Comment: Why not provide your own implementation of `ExecutorService` by wrapping an existing one, which resubmit tasks that failed submission due to the resizing?

Comment: @daniu that is a workaround. The point of the questions is why should the pool ever throw a RejectedExecutionException if I never submit more that the queueCapacity+maxThreads. I am never changing the max threads so by ThreadPoolExecutor's definition, it should either accommodate the task in a Thread or to the queue.

Comment: Ok I seem to have misunderstood your question. What is it? Do you want to know why the behavior takes place or how you get around it causing problems for you?

Comment: Yes, changing my implementation to an executor service is not feasible since a lot of the code refers to the ThreadPoolExecutor. So if I still wanted to have a resizable ThreadPoolExecutor I need to know how I can fix it. May the right way to do something like this is to extend ThreadPoolExecutor and get access to some of its protected variables and update the pool size within a synchronized block on a lock shared by the super class.

Comment: Extending `ThreadPoolExecutor` is very probably a bad idea, and wouldn't you need to change existing code in this case as well? It'd be best you provide some example of how your actual code accesses the executor. I'd be surprised if it used many methods specific to `ThreadPoolExecutor` (ie not in `ExecutorService`).

Comment: I believe ThreadPoolExecutor is in fact designed for extension. There are even extension methods like `beforeExecute` and `afterExecute` that subclasses can override to customize the behavior. There is nothing special about the way the actual code uses it. They refer to it as a `ThreadPoolExecutor` and in many cases, changing that code is not feasible because of ownership and access to source-code etc.

Comment: Not clear what you're really trying to achieve. Isn't  [Executors.newCachedThreadPool()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newCachedThreadPool()) what you want (no queue, immediate execution)? Please clarify.

Comment: Cached thread pool has no upper bound on the total number of threads. That can quickly lead to out of memory error

Comment: Then set an upper bound. I still don't understand what the problem is.

Comment: How do you set an upper bound on a cached thread pool

Comment: I meant you can use your ThreadPoolExecutor. Just set a corePoolSize that is high enough and that's all. You don't need to change it dynamically.

Comment: @Olivier sometimes that is just not feasible. My example is a minimal toy example so that other can reproduce the issue. In production there could be other constraints on why I may not be able to "just allocate a high thread count for perpetuity" - consider something like a multi-tenant environment where many clients use-cases are running and you need to be able to optimize where the resources of your application are allocated. Sure, I can throw more hardware at it and call it a day but that is added cost that your customers will have to eventually pay for.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209635/discussion-between-swaranga-sarma-and-olivier).

Answer (score 5):

Here is a scenario why this is happening:

In my example I use minThreads = 0,  maxThreads = 2 and queueCapacity = 2 to make it shorter.
The first command gets submitted, this is done in the method execute:

```
public void execute(Runnable command) {
    if (command == null)
        throw new NullPointerException();
    /*
     * Proceed in 3 steps:
     *
     * 1. If fewer than corePoolSize threads are running, try to
     * start a new thread with the given command as its first
     * task.  The call to addWorker atomically checks runState and
     * workerCount, and so prevents false alarms that would add
     * threads when it shouldn't, by returning false.
     *
     * 2. If a task can be successfully queued, then we still need
     * to double-check whether we should have added a thread
     * (because existing ones died since last checking) or that
     * the pool shut down since entry into this method. So we
     * recheck state and if necessary roll back the enqueuing if
     * stopped, or start a new thread if there are none.
     *
     * 3. If we cannot queue task, then we try to add a new
     * thread.  If it fails, we know we are shut down or saturated
     * and so reject the task.
     */
    int c = ctl.get();
    if (workerCountOf(c) < corePoolSize) {
        if (addWorker(command, true))
            return;
        c = ctl.get();
    }
    if (isRunning(c) && workQueue.offer(command)) {
        int recheck = ctl.get();
        if (! isRunning(recheck) && remove(command))
            reject(command);
        else if (workerCountOf(recheck) == 0)
            addWorker(null, false);
    }
    else if (!addWorker(command, false))
        reject(command);
}
```

for this command workQueue.offer(command) than addWorker(null, false) is executed. 
The worker thread first takes this command out of the queue in the thread run method, so at this time  the queue still has one command,

The second command gets submitted this time  workQueue.offer(command) is executed. Now the queue is full

Now the ScheduledExecutorService executes the resizeThreadPool method which calls setCorePoolSize with maxThreads.
Here is the method setCorePoolSize:

```
 public void setCorePoolSize(int corePoolSize) {
    if (corePoolSize < 0)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    int delta = corePoolSize - this.corePoolSize;
    this.corePoolSize = corePoolSize;
    if (workerCountOf(ctl.get()) > corePoolSize)
        interruptIdleWorkers();
    else if (delta > 0) {
        // We don't really know how many new threads are "needed".
        // As a heuristic, prestart enough new workers (up to new
        // core size) to handle the current number of tasks in
        // queue, but stop if queue becomes empty while doing so.
        int k = Math.min(delta, workQueue.size());
        while (k-- > 0 && addWorker(null, true)) {
            if (workQueue.isEmpty())
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

This method adds one worker using addWorker(null, true). No there are 2 worker queues running, the maximum and the queue is full.

The third command gets submitted and fails because  workQueue.offer(command) and addWorker(command, false) fails, leading to the Exception:

```
java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: Task java.util.concurrent.FutureTask@24c22fe rejected from java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@cd1e646[Running, pool size = 2, active threads = 2, queued tasks = 2, completed tasks = 0]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$AbortPolicy.rejectedExecution(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:2047)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.reject(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:823)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.execute(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1369)
at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:112)
at ThreadPoolResizeTest.executeOnce(ThreadPoolResizeTest.java:60)
at ThreadPoolResizeTest.runTest(ThreadPoolResizeTest.java:28)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:263)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:69)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:48)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:292)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:365)
```

I think to solve this problem you should set the capacityof the queue to the maximum of commands you want to execute.

Comment: Correct. I was able to repro by copying the code to my own class and adding loggers. Basically, when the queue is full, and I submit a new task, it will try to create a new Worker. Meanwhile if at that moment, my resizer also calls setCorePoolSize to 2, that also creates a new Worker. At this point, two Workers are competing to be added but they both can't be because it would violate the max-pool-size constraint so the new task submission gets rejected. I think this is a race condition and I filed a bug report to OpenJDK. Lets see. But you answered my question so you get the bounty. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this qualifies as bug. This is the behavior when the additional workers threads are created after the queue is full but this has been kind of noted in java docs that caller has to deal with tasks being rejected.

Java docs

> Factory for new threads. All threads are created using this
>        factory (via method addWorker).  All callers must be prepared
>        for addWorker to fail, which may reflect a system or user's
>        policy limiting the number of threads.  Even though it is not
>        treated as an error, failure to create threads may result in
>        new tasks being rejected or existing ones remaining stuck in
>        the queue.

When you resize the core pool size, lets say increase, the additional workers are created (`addWorker` method in `setCorePoolSize`) and the call to create additional work (`addWorker` method from `execute`)  is rejected when the `addWorker` returns false (`add Worker` last code snippet) as the enough additional workers are already created by `setCorePoolSize` **but not run yet to reflect the update in the queue**.

Relevant parts

Compare

```
public void setCorePoolSize(int corePoolSize) {
    ....
    int k = Math.min(delta, workQueue.size());
    while (k-- > 0 && addWorker(null, true)) {
        if (workQueue.isEmpty())
             break;
    }
}

public void execute(Runnable command) {
    ...
    int c = ctl.get();
    if (workerCountOf(c) < corePoolSize) {
        if (addWorker(command, true))
            return;
        c = ctl.get();
    }
    if (isRunning(c) && workQueue.offer(command)) {
        int recheck = ctl.get();
        if (! isRunning(recheck) && remove(command))
            reject(command);
        else if (workerCountOf(recheck) == 0)
            addWorker(null, false);
    }
    else if (!addWorker(command, false))
        reject(command);
}

private boolean addWorker(Runnable firstTask, boolean core) {
....
   if (wc >= CAPACITY || wc >= (core ? corePoolSize : maximumPoolSize))
     return false;             
}
```

Use custom retry rejection execution handler ( This should work for your case as you have upper bound as max pool size ).  Please adjust as needed.

```
public static class RetryRejectionPolicy implements RejectedExecutionHandler {
    public RetryRejectionPolicy () {}

    public void rejectedExecution(Runnable r, ThreadPoolExecutor e) {
        if (!e.isShutdown()) {
           while(true)
            if(e.getQueue().offer(r)) break;
        }
    }
}

ThreadPoolExecutor pool = new ThreadPoolExecutor(
      minThreads, maxThreads,
      0, TimeUnit.SECONDS,
      new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>(queueCapacity),
      new ThreadPoolResizeTest.RetryRejectionPolicy()
 );
```

Also note your use of shutdown is not correct as this will not wait for submitted task to complete execution but use with `awaitTermination` instead.

Comment: I think shutdown waits for already submitted tasks, according to  the JavaDoc: shutdown()
Initiates an orderly shutdown in which previously submitted tasks are executed, but no new tasks will be accepted.

Comment: @ThomasKrieger -  It will execute the already submitted tasks but will not wait them to finish - from docs https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html#shutdown() - This method does not wait for previously submitted tasks to complete execution. Use awaitTermination to do that.